# Variable name in iron router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I want to assign a variable to a route's name property in an iron router route in my meteor application but whenever I try to do so the application crashes.

```
Router.route('/:tpl', function(){
    this.render(this.params.tpl)
}, {
    name:variableName // I tried name:this.params.tpl also
});
```

The main purpose of this is to set the document title of the page on the basis of the route name by below code

```
Router.onAfterAction(function() {
    document.title = Router.current().route.getName();
});
```

Whenever I set the route name to a string the code works but when I assign a variable to route name then the code breaks.

Note - I'm using the latest version of Meteor and Iron Router.

Comment: Have  you tried to assign a function which returns your variable? Something like : "name: function() { return variableName }".

Comment: Couple questions: What's the error? Where and how is your variable declared?

Comment: @ko0stik Yes I tried adding a function to name which returned a variable containing `this.params.tpl`, the application builds successfully but routing stops working. Error shows **The route named "undefined" does not match the path**

Comment: @Julien Variable is defined above `this.render(this.params.tpl)`. Basically I want the value of **this.params.tpl** as the route name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a variable route name. The route name is used by iron router to identify the route, think of it like the route's ID.

What you could do for your purpose, as you apparently want to have the template name in the title:

```
Router.onAfterAction(function() {
    document.title = this.params.tpl;
});
```